# Search string and return line containing the string

Tags: php, search

I have to create website using php that can search a word and return a line containing the word from 3 input text that been fixed. I've able to search a word and check whether it exist inside the input text. How can i search and return the output a line containing the word

here are some data from the input file

```
<paragraph><Date><Date>TUESDAY</Date></Date>. <Date>MARCH 3, 1903</Date>
Outstation Prosperity.
</paragraph>
<paragraph>THE perusal of the various Annual Reports from Outstations is interesting: and very minutely shows the work of the Country.
</paragraph>
```

here are my coding that i have done

```
<?php
$path = 'D:\Collective Intelligence\assignment&project\PROJECT-DATASET';
$findThisString = $_POST['search1'];

$dir = dir($path);

// Get next file/dir name in directory
while (false !== ($file = $dir->read()))
{   
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
    {
        // Is this entry a file or directory?
        if (is_file($path . '/' . $file))
        {
            // Its a file, yay! Lets get the file's contents
            $data = file_get_contents($path . '/' . $file);

            // Is the str in the data (case-insensitive search)
            if (stripos($data, $findThisString) !== false)
            {
                // sw00t! we have a match
            echo 'match found in ' . $file . "<br>\n";

            }
        }
    }
}

$dir->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fgets` to check out those lines that you want. Just add a simple counter:

```
if (is_file($path . '/' . $file)) {
    // Its a file, yay! Lets get the file's contents
    $data = file_get_contents($path . '/' . $file);

    $fh = fopen($path . '/' . $file, 'r');
    $i = 1;
    while(!feof($fh)) {
        $line = fgets($fh);
        if(stripos($line, $findThisString) !== false) {
            echo "match {$findThisString} found in line {$i}<br/>\n";
        }
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
```